# error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘;’ token getch();

Tags: c++

Whenever I run this code, I get error "sample.cpp:74:8: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘;’ token
getch();"

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stream>
#include<new>
#include<stdio.h>
#define SQ(x)(x)*(x)
#define RESP(x) 1.0/(x)
#define free_arg char*
#define nr_end 1
#define TINY 1.0e-20

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned long int us;

double *dvector (long n1, long nh);
long *lvector (long n1, long nh);
double **matrix (long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch);
long **lmatrix (long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch);
double ***f3tensor (long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch);
void free_vector (long *v,long nl,long nh);
void free_lvector (long *v,long nl,long nh);
void free_matrix (long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch);
void free_lmatrix (long **m, long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch);
void free_tensor(double ***t, long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch, long ndl, long ndh);



//define
#define F(x) ((x)*(x)*(x))-(x) + 1
#define ESP 0.001
using namespace std;
// function x^3 -x +1

int main()
{
int i=1;
float x0,x1,x2;
double f1,f2,f0,t;

cout<<"Enter the value of x0:"<<"/n";
cin>>x0;
//cout<<F(x0)<</n;

cout<<"ENter thr value of x1"<<"/n";
cin>>x1;



do
{
    x2=(x0+x1)/2.0;
    f0=F(x0);
    f1=F(x1);
    f2=F(x2);
    
    if(f0*f2<0)
    {
        x1=x2;
        
    }
    else
    {
    x0=x2;
    }
    i++;
}while((f1)*(f2)>ESP);
            {
        cout<< "\n\n root="<<x2<<endl;
            }
 return 0;
cout<<"\n"<<x0<<"\n"<<x1<<"\n"<<x2<<"\n"<<f0<<"\n"<<f2;
}
getch();
```

How to solve this issue?? P.S. This is a bisection method Assignment tell me if any other error visible. I think there's some minor issue with getch but I can't resolve it right now.

Comment: I think it's a typo: `getch()` is outside main, just move it one line up. Btw. the code after the `return`-statement will never be reached. You can remove the `return 0;` it's not needed in `main`.

Comment: getch() appears to need curses.h included.-- Unrelated comments: Put #defined expressions in parentheses, i.e. `#define SQ(x) ((x)*(x))`. Use typedef, not preprocessor defines, for type aliases.Indent your code properly (that would have made this error obvious)!-- Oh, and churill is right.

Comment: what do you exect to gain from all those `#define`s ? (other than obfuscating your code)

Comment: for example try `auto x = F(2) / 2;` to see how bad macros can be